# Execute commands on tmux detach

Tags: shell, shell-script, tmux

Is it possible to execute commands on `tmux` detach?

I usually have a rails console and server running in the `tmux` session, on detach is it possible to automatically end those?

Comment: The whole point of detaching from a session is that programs running inside the session are unaware that it has happened.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT, `tmux` didn't provide hooking on detach, attach events. But you can always send a command to a detached session, using `tmux send`:

```
tmux send -t session_name.panel '<command><Enter>'
```

Example:

```
$ tmux new -s foo
```

Pressing `bind-key` + <kbd>d</kbd> to detach. Then:

```
$ tmux send -t foo 'echo foo<Enter>'
$ tmux attach -t foo
```

and you will see the word *foo*.

Note that `<Enter>` here mean you type the literal <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: can we automate these tasks without touching any keys?

Comment: @32r34wgf3e were you able to automate it ?